# How to manage Ansible architecture to ensure fast deployment in case of light scripts

Tags: python, git, ansible, roles

As far as I understand, the most natural thing to do, when it comes to decide an Ansible architecture, is to split the main playbook in multiple roles, one for each component of the application. Each role should have it's own repository.

All this roles being "glued" in my main yaml, that is commited in main git repository, that refers to roles repositories through requirements.yml. For instance, if I want to deploy a regular apache/tomcat/war, the main requirements.yml looks like this :

```
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.checks.hardware.requirements
  version: "1.0.0"
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.deploys.apache
  version: "1.0.0"
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.deploys.certificates
  version: "1.0.0"
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.deploys.jdk
  version: "1.0.0"
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.deploys.tomcat
  version: "1.0.0"
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.deploys.db.client
  version: "1.0.0"
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.deploys.war
  version: "1.0.0"
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.configure.logrotation
  version: "1.0.0"
```

Okay, that looks great. I'm convinced by the architecture : each package is self-consistent, everything is versioned. I'm pretty confident on what I deploy.

### Now let's add some 'light' scripts

Let's now say, I want to add a python script that is launched through cron and that send a mail every day to report the activity. If I apply the same strategy as above, I need to add something like this to my requirements :

```
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.deploys.python
  version: "1.0.0"
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.deploys.pip
  version: "1.0.0"
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.uses.pip.to.deploy.python.packages
  version: "1.0.0"
- src: git+https://git.with.role.that.deploys.my.python.script.and.register.it.in.cron
  version: "1.0.0"
```

But now, I'm not so convinced. Usage of this looks pretty heavy for such a light script.

Let's say that I deployed this, and now I want to make a minor update, on my script that induce a new package to being needed. What I should do is :

- commit/pull_request/tag my script update in the script repo
- commit/pull_request/tag the new pip import in the pip repo
- commit/pull_request both new tags in main repo
- pull the main repo on the Ansible-launching machine
- re-execute the pip import role
- re-execute the script deploy role

That looks like a ton of work for a light update like this. As I just add three lines of python, I would expect for the process to be much lighter.

[EDIT]

In our case, we are developing our python scripts on a developer machine, then using Ansible to deploy it on "Dev" environment.

But the developer machine do not allows to perform every end-to-end test cases. We have to run some tests on the "Dev" machines.

It makes that the deployment process may be run multiple times for some of our developments. Which make it's heaviness hard to accept.

[/EDIT]

### What I thought about

- I thought I could merge the two last repositories. It has backdraws (like the fact I have to go through pip packages installation to update my script), but it spare one pull_request. It looks like a bad compromise
- More generally, I could merge some/all these roles. It would easy the deployment process, but it slow down the execution time, as full operations are processed again.
- I thought I should build a script that does the previously-described operation for me. That's my best shot for now, and that's why I'm here.

### Question

So, the question is : How to manage Ansible architecture to ensure fast deployment in case of light scripts ? Fast deployment means both :

- I do not need to manually do a lot of things (multiple merge requests ...)
- Ansible will not perform heavy unwanted tasks (like checking all packages as I just changed a script)

There must be a basic concept I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After questioning local specialists, I summarize here what they said :

According to most of the asked people :

- the issue is **not** the heaviness of the python's script update process (as described in the question).
- the issue is the frequency we call it (which was not described in the question. My bad. I update the question right now).

Most of the asked people suggested we should commit from the very same machine that is tested.

We should :

- first make our python's script developments on this machine and test it works
- then commit from this machine
- then redeploy through Ansible and test again.

This way, we only need to deploy python script once the developments are tested.

What we are doing: [image: Ansible is part of the test loop]

What we should do: [image: Ansible is not part of the test loop]

Additionally, two non-exclusive strategy were advised to help reduce the heaviness:

1. grouping in a single role everything that often change together (like python packages and python script), and be sure to uses checks in order to only deploy-redeploy what is needed (typically do not redeploy every python package). Maybe use tags to specify what to deploy.
2. use a third-party automate, like Jenkins, to launch commonly used task sequence, like deploy python script (through the process described in the question).